# Parsing a stdout in Python

Tags: python

In Python I need to get the version of an external binary I need to call in my script.

Let's say that I want to use [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) in Python and I want to know its version.

I will call

```
os.system( "wget --version | grep Wget" )
```

and then I will parse the outputted string.

How to redirect the stdout of the os.command in a string in Python?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/how-to-call-external-command-in-python

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One "old" way is:

```
fin,fout=os.popen4("wget --version | grep Wget")
print fout.read()
```

The other modern way is to use a `subprocess` module:

```
import subprocess
cmd = subprocess.Popen('wget --version', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in cmd.stdout:
    if "Wget" in line:
        print line
```

Comment: subprocess is new since python 2.4.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `subprocess` module:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p1 = Popen(["wget", "--version"], stdout=PIPE)
p2 = Popen(["grep", "Wget"], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
output = p2.communicate()[0]
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `subprocess` instead.

Comment: does `Subprocess.popen` calls shell to parse command and runs an extra process in Python.

Comment: @Grijesh: Only if you tell it to.

Comment: In 'C' I only use low level `pipe()`  but in Python I saw people use `subproces.popen()` even there is `os.pipe()`. which practice is good? Although I can see `subprocess.popen()` is more powerful then `C` `popen()` we can explicitly send parsed command in python.

Answer (score -3):

If you are on *nix, I would recommend you to use commands module.

```
import commands

status, res = commands.getstatusoutput("wget --version | grep Wget")

print status # Should be zero in case of of success, otherwise would have an error code
print res # Contains stdout
```

Comment: bad advice: doesn't exist in py3k, docs say: Using the **`subprocess`**  module is preferable to using the commands module.