# Call a system command inside Python and get its output result, not the exit status

Tags: python

In Python, I want to count the number of lines in a file `xh-2.txt`.

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("wc -l xh-2.txt",shell=True)
```

But this is giving me exit status, not the result of the command.

I know the command `print os.popen("wc -l xh-2.txt|cut -d' ' -f1").read()` will do the job,
but popen is depreciated and why use read()?

What is the best way to call a system command inside Python and get its output result, not exit status?

Comment: possible duplicate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101426/parsing-a-stdout-in-python
Use Popen instead as described there. And read STDOUT like the top answers do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [subprocess.check_output()](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

> Run command with arguments and return its output as a byte string.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import shlex
>>> cmd = 'wc -l test.txt'
>>> cm = shlex.split(cmd)
>>> subprocess.check_output(cm,shell=True)
'      1 test.txt\n'
>>>
```

Comment: i just don't want the filename in the output, weird thing is python doc didn't tell me

Comment: filename will be there in the output because it is present when you run `wc -l test.txt` independently in your shell. You can do this `subprocess.check_output(cm).strip().split(' ')[0]`

Answer (score 2):

You could use subprocess [recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#replacing-older-functions-with-the-subprocess-module)

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
Popen("wc -l xh-2.txt", shell=True, stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

Comment: #method 1
    os.system("wc -l xh-2.txt|cut -d' ' -f1 > tmp")
    print open("tmp","r").readline()
#method 2
    from subprocess import check_output
    sts = check_output("wc -l xh-2.txt")
    print re.compile(r'(\d+) ').search(sts).groups()[0]